# I am trying to collect the count value when the button is pressed.but longer press the button it increases the value by several times

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to increment the count by 1 when the button is pressed but when I press and hold then it increases the count value more than just one increment. Here is the code.

```
while True:
      if pin==1:
         count +=1
      else:
         count=0
```

Comment: What are you expecting? Your code sets the count to 0 when the button isn't pressed and increments it by one for every cycle while the button is pressed. The behavior you are expecting lines up with what the code is doing.

Comment: Unless you are trying to *set* the count to 1, not *increment* it by 1 every cycle, in which case, just change the `count += 1` to `count = 1`

Comment: i was unintentionally making it reset when the button is pressed but now i rectified . but the problem remains same. i tried above statement but it's the count values doesn't increase.

Comment: How do you know that? You aren't even printing te value of `count` to the terminal?

Comment: i solved it by myself